# Как отрисовать массив элементов с помощью цикла for

Tags: c#, unity3d, list, for

нужна помощь. У меня есть карточки монстров, которые привязаны к конкретным объектам. Мне надо, чтобы при вызове метода `AddEnemyToQueue(EnemyName)` проверялось, есть ли карточка с таким именем в папке Resources и если `MatchInArray` != null, то поместить карточку с именем этого врага в лист `ListElements<GameObjects>` и отрисовать каждый элемент из этого списка с помощью цикла for.

Пусть, есть бесконечное количество команд `AddEnemyToQueue`, тогда и количество элементов`<GameObject>` в нем бесконечно, для этого есть переменная `int MaxElements = x`, которая ограничивает отрисовку элементов в Unity, чтобы не отрисовывать бесконечное количество элементов.

При отрисовке всех элементов`ListElements<GameObject>` выдается следующая ошибка.

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index

```
public List<GameObject> ListElements = new List<GameObject>();

public string[] TileNames = new string[] { };
TileNames = Directory.GetFiles(TileNamesPath);

private void AddEnemyToQueue(string EnemyName)
{
    //Check if Tile with enemy name exists
    var MatchInArray = TileNames.Where(item => item.Contains(EnemyName)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (MatchInArray != null)
    {
        
        ListElements.Add(Resources.Load<GameObject>(TilePrefabDir+EnemyName));
        
        for (int l = 0; l < MaxElements; l++)
        {
            GameObject ListElement = Instantiate(ListElements[l]);
            ListElement.transform.SetParent(ContentContainer.transform, false);
            ListElement.name = l.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

*Первая карточка с индексом [0] символизирует врага на поле с которым дерется игрок*

Comment: Нуу наверное `ListElements.Add` нужно внутрь цикла перенести. Хотя всё-равно код странный.

Comment: Сам объект добавляется в лист без проблем и отображается в нем. Проблема в том, что если отрисовывать все элементы листа(циклом for), то выдает ошибку. А если добавить внутрь цикла, то объект будет дублироваться много раз. Я пытался делать и с помощью insert(l, Object), но все равно такая же проблема.

Comment: Да, а что у вас в `MaxElements` и какая предполагалась вообще логика? Нужен ли там вообще этот цикл?

Comment: Количество `MaxElements` является ограничителем для отрисовки элементов в unity. Пусть количество `ListElements` бесконечно, но рисоваться будет столько, сколько указано в MaxElements(число).  Возможно его стоит заменить на элемент Mask, но я не знаю, ограничивает ли количество отображаемых элементов их подгрузку (нагрузку на систему).

Comment: Ну просто вы перебираете `ListElements` с индексом от `0` до `MaxElements-1`, вы уверены, что там есть столько элементов? Может нужно перебирать до `ListElements.Count`? Я правда всё-равно логику не понимаю, зачем там вообще перебор.

Comment: Перебор для того, чтобы отрисовать каждый элемент<GameObject> в родительском трансформе, так как в условии перебора есть функция `Instantiate`. `ListElements.Count` невозможен по причине бесконечного количества элементов. Каждый элемент `ListElements` добавляется в массив динамически (во время действия игры). а идея MaxElements-1 может сработать, надо попробовать.

Comment: Что значит "бесконечное количество элементов"? У вас сначала там ноль элементов, а при каждом вызове `AddEnemyToQueue` добавляется один элемент.

Comment: Хотел добавить ответ, если я всё правильно понял наконец-то, но вам нужно перевести вопрос на русский язык, чтобы всё было согласно правил, тогда его переоткроют и я смогу ответить.

Comment: Вероятно, количество элементов в списке не кратно `MaxElements`. | Вместо `for` можно использовать `foreach (var elem in ListElements.Take(MaxElements))`

Comment: `ListElements` - не используйте венгерскую нотацию. Назовите список просто `elements`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а если это set или map или просто массив? как отличить?

Comment: @CrazyElf, да действительно помог перебор списка до предпоследнего значения `MaxElements-1`. Проблема была в разности синтаксиса и арифметического подсчета. Лист считает с нуля, а другой элемент с 1, поэтому из-за этой разницы и выдавалась ошибка. При удалении указатель обращался к несуществующему элементу, который уже сдвинулся на предыдущее место. Если напишешь респонд, то я помечу как ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: @KaelKaelich Я честно говоря так и не понял в чём тут суть. Можете сами ответ написать )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выход за границы массива. Наверняка в `ListElements` количество элементов меньше, чем указано в `MaxElements`. Смотрите в отладчике что у вас в `MaxElements` и совпадает ли это число с количеством в списке. А если не уверены, то надо перед циклом делать проверку о совпадаении количества, либо в цикле, если `l` меньше количества, то делать `break`

Comment: `MaxElements` количество отрисовываемых элементов в условной панели в unity. Пусть количество элементов `ListElements` бесконечно, тогда `MaxElements` разделяет их по X элементов во избежание нагрузки системы.

Comment: так, и что? в вашем коде нет разделения по N. В вашем коде идёт цикл до одного значения, а значения берутся из списка с длиной другого значения.